# How to combine shell commands

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to make a script that will copy files from a directory and place the copied files into a new directory.

I know that the `cp` command will copy the files and the `mkdir` command will create the directory but does anyone know how to combines these 2 commands into a single line?

So far I have

```
mkdir /root/newdir/ cp /root/*.doc /root/newdir
```

this gives the error message

```
mkdir: cannot create directory 'cp': Files exists
mkdir: cannot create directory '/root/files/wp.doc: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory 'mkdir' : File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory '/root/files/new dir: file exists
```

However it does create the directory `newdir`

Answer (score 8):

```
mkdir -p /root/newdir/ && cp /root/*.doc /root/newdir/
```

This will call `mkdir` to create directory structure, check if command execution was successful and call `cp` command if it was.

Comment: This works thanks very much although it does come up with the error message... cp: omitting directory 'mkdir'

Comment: @user1065861: `cp` does not copy directories by default. You have to specify `-p` option if you want it to do so. Check contents of your `/root` directory - it is likely you have created unintended directories there while playing with those commands.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their help it is now copying fine, however, I am also looking for the command that will take the files from the new directory /root/newdir and replace the files in /root. /root/newdir is basically a backup directory. The command I have so far is.... tar xvzf /root/newdir*.* ;

Comment: @user1065861: I'd suggest you ask this question separately. Also, take a look at `rsync`, it does it for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir /root/newdir/; cp /root/*.doc /root/newdir
```

Answer (score 0):

Place semicolon between two commands

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you do not tell the shell where exactly the commands end. In this case:

```
mkdir /root/newdir/ cp /root/*.doc /root/newdir
```

Your command `cp` will go as an argument to the `mkdir` command and shell tries to make the file named `cp`. Same happens to all other.

By putting the `;` after commands. It tells the shell that command has been ended and next word is an another command.

newline (Return key) is also treated as the command seprator. So if you put each command in next line, it also works fine.
So you can try either of these:

```
mkdir /root/newdir/  ; cp /root/*.doc /root/newdir
```

OR

```
mkdir /root/newdir/ 

cp /root/*.doc /root/newdir
```

Comment: Good explanation, but for the solution I prefer [`&&`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8271018/667820) over `;`  as the former takes care of the possibility of a `mkdir` failure.